# unable to execute PowerShell script with windows message via batch file

Tags: winforms, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple PowerShell script that using windows.forms for presenting and getting data using GUI.
It works when I run it using PowerShell , but doesn't work via CMD.
Here is the .ps1 example :

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('message','Step 1','YesNoCancel','Question')
```

batch file for executing :

```
powershell "&{start-process powershell -ArgumentList ' -noprofile -file c:\temp\gui.ps1' -verb RunAs} exit $LASTEXITCODE" < NUL
```

Th error I get is : Unable to find type [System.Windows.MessageBox].
I understood that the CMD running with different context and the assembly need to be loaded , so I tried to load it from the CMD command , but still same error .

```
powershell "&{[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); start-process powershell -ArgumentList ' -noprofile -file c:\temp\gui.ps1' -verb RunAs} exit $LASTEXITCODE" < NUL
```

Error:
[image]
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```dos
PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\temp\gui.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"; Exit $LastExitCode
```

*this is completely untested*

Comment: I have updated my answer with a fuller command, please feel free to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figure it out.
The issue was with the  PowerShell script,
I used a [System.Windows.MessageBox] instead a [System.Windows.**Forms**.MessageBox]
Before:

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('message','Step 1','YesNoCancel','Question')
```

After:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('message','Step 1','YesNoCancel','Question')
```

It works without changing the batch file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following in the batch file:

```
powershell -command [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('message','Step 1','YesNoCancel','Question')
```

I hope this is helpful, if you have any other questions, please comment below.

Comment: Does not explain why original command works in powershell console and not in powershell interpret executed from batch.